# Difference between ASSOCIATOR OF and ManagementObjectCollection method GetRelated

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v, wmi-query, wql

I've noticed that with WMI queries, ie WQL - SQL for WMI, that you can utilize Associators to access 2 classes in the same namespace like Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData and Msvm_ResourceAllocationSettingData that are a part of \root\virtualization\v2.

Are ASSOCIATORS the same as ManagementObjectCollection's GetRelated Method?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as per MSDN documentation of `ManagementObject.GetRelated()`

> The operation is equivalent to an ASSOCIATORS OF query where ResultClass = relatedClass.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89k086yy(v=vs.110).aspx